# Dynamic extraction of tweets using python and tweepy that is whenever new tweet is posted it should be immediately extracted.

Tags: python, tweepy

I am using Python and tweepy API to extract tweets of specific keywords. However, now I want to extract tweets from a single page but the problem is that tweet should automatically extracted whenever that page posts the new tweet. Can anyone please tell me how to do that as I don't know when the new tweet would be posted?

Comment: Twitter has Streaming API to do this job. check this https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/consuming-streaming-data

Comment: Yes but the problem is that I don't know when the latest tweets would be updated so the api should automatically get a new tweet whenever that is posted